# Properties of the operator$ T(f)(x)=\int_0^x e^{-y}f(y)dy$ on $C[0,1]$ with sup norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $C[0,1]$ denote the space of real valued continous functions on $[0,1]$ equiped with the sup norm $||^.||_{\infty}$.Let $T:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ be the linear operator defined by

$T(f)(x)=\int_0^x e^{-y}f(y)dy$

Then

1) $T$ is surjective.

2) $||I+T||=1+||T||$

3)$I-T$ is not invertible.

4)$||T||=1$

I know the answer to this question from this source(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3608818/710290) but I do have the following confusion/problem.

3) $I-T$ is  inverible.Then I should be able to show $Ker(I-T)=\{0\}$.

If possible, let $f\in Ker(I-T)$ be non-zero.Then

$T(f)(x)=f(x)$

$\Rightarrow\int_0^x e^{-y}f(y) dy=f(x) $. $\quad (1)$

Obviously $f(x)$ is differentiable by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus .So differentiating $(1)$ , we get

$e^{-x}f(x)=f'(x)$

$\Rightarrow f(x)=e^{-e^{-x}}+C$.

Again from $(1)$ ,

$\int_0^x e^{-y}(e^{-e^{-y}}+C)dy=e^{-e^{-x}}+C$

$\Rightarrow e^{-e^{-x}}-1/e+C(1-e^{-x})=e^{-{e^{-x}}}+C$

$\Rightarrow e^{x-1}=-C $ 
 $ \forall x$. What to say about C from here? Where am I wrong?

Also in $(2)$ , I am unable to show $||I+T||\ge1+||T||$ using constant function .Please help.

Comment: I don't think that T is surjective. Unless I am missing something, $T f$ is always continuously differentiable, but there are non-differentiable continuous functions.

Comment: yes..T is not surjective as you already  pointed out the reason.

Comment: I think I may have figured.out the answer to.my  first question.I started out with an assumption which leads to absurd conclusion( for any $C$). So my assumption is not tenable